# File Encryption in Swift with AES

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, aes

My objective is to encrypt a selected file and save it in Documents Directory. I could have used Apple Encrypted Archive to encrypt but the file decryption has to be done on my server (Java).

The java code I'm using to encrypt on the android app.

```
public static void performEncrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile) {
    try {
        String SECRET_KEY = "MY_SECRETE_KEY";
        String SALT = "MY_SALT_KEY";
        // Generating Secrete Key
        byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.toCharArray(), SALT.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
        
        //Reading Input File Bytes
        byte[] inputBytes = Files.readAllBytes(inputFile.toPath());
        
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
        // Performing Encryption
        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
        
        //Writing to output file
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        outputStream.write(outputBytes);
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've been trying to replicate the above function is Swift but I am having trouble finding the Swift alternative of these Java Classes. How do I perform encryption using my salt and secrete key ? The closest article I could find related to my issue was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53195595/swift-aes-encrypt-and-decrypt-gets-different-results), but I couldn't understand it.

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let tempFileName = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("temp.enc")
    do{
        let iv: [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        let fileToEncrypt = try Data(contentsOf: urls.first!)
        let operations = CCOperation(kCCEncrypt)
        let algorithm = CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES)
        let options = CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
        

    }catch{
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

The last option for me would be to convert my Java code into Objective-c using [j2objc](https://developers.google.com/j2objc).

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched Apple Developer resources for encryption libraries?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried the Apple Encrypted Archive framework. I was able to encrypt and decrypt a file but it's of no use because the framework itself derives parameters, keys, and other data from the encrypted source file when decrypting and I need to decrypt this file on my java server.

Comment: Also tried RNCryptor library that has implementation in Swift and Java and it works but it won't be a permanent solution as changing Server-side code will be an expensive operation for my project.